# Using mod_rewrite to redirect home page ONLY on HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I followed this example "using-mod-rewrite-to-redirect-home-page-only" but I'm not sure it functions on a https/SSL
The site home page is https://www.somasimple.com and I want it to be redirected to https://www.somasimple.com/forums/home
I tried without success this at the end of the htaccess file =>

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somasimple\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.somasimple.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ forums/home [L]
```

Comment: Use **R** flag  to redirect the url. Just Replace **[L]** with **[L,R]** in your last rule.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from https://www.somasimple.com to https://www.somasimple.com/forums/home just add a simple redirect match in virtualhost, no need for mod_rewrite or any other convoluted messes you may find out there.

```
<Virtualhost *:443>
   ServerName www.somasimple.com
   DocumentRoot /path/to/docroot
   SSLEngine on
   #.... (other SSL directives)

   # Redirect / to /forums/home
   RedirectMatch ^/$ /forums/home
</Virtualhost>
```